# How to add pictures to OpenLayers map using GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, image

I have web map showing land parcel and buildings.I am using GeoServer WMS and OpenLayers.
My buildings are showing as point on map. Then I want to add some images to those points to show when activating image layer just like [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/georss-flickr.html) example

According to that example I think GeoRSS is the solution. But I have lot of problems just like,

1. What types of things should do in GeoServer
2. Where store images etc...

Please give some idea. Is there any tutorials or example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoRSS is used in that example because Flickr providing geotagged images through a GeoRSS API.

There are several solutions here, but I recon that most of them require you to write some OpenLayers code, and unless you use a photo storing site such as Flickr, you would have to write your own mechanisms for storing and retriewing your images as well.

A tip is to use PostGIS or another spatial databse, and return the image data as GeoJSON, with a feature attribute with a link to the image. I did something like this in my masters thesis 3 years ago, using Google Maps API. The code is horrible, but could give you some ideas perhaps. You'll find it at [my homepage](http://code.atlefren.net/masters/)

Comment: Hallo atlefren,

Comment: Are u do that using open layers,I can't find open layer code on your sourcecode_masters_atlefren folder,Pls correct me

Comment: As I wrote: I did this implementation using Google Maps API, and linked to my code as a means of inspiration only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

You Geotiff as your picture type to publish using geoserver.

It works fine for me.